# AndroidStudio crash on macOS Big Sur beta

Tags: macos-big-sur, android-studio-4.1

After update to last beta release of macOS Big (11.0 Beta (20A5395g)) - Android Studio (4.1) keeps shutting because
`[NSOpenGLContext setView:] must be called from the main thread.`
This happens very often so I have to open AS every 5 minutes again and again

Also there are other issue - ANR (or very laggy functioning) that I was tolerating so far - related to opened sub-windows like

- open ADV manager
- creating new project - choosing activity for application
- importing project from VCS.

BigSur beta is SO UNSTABLE so it drive me crazy.
Do You recommend any AndroidStudio or macOS canary/beta channels that fix those issues?

**EDIT** 17.11.2020

Looks like after 2 installation of 11.0.1 problem is fixed

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64837992/6482350)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any chance that you have external monitors connected? I'm experiencing the same issue and the crash happens whenever any Android Studio window is in the external monitors. This is a known and resolved JDK bug (see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-2790). I know of two workarounds, but they are both not ideal:

1. Don't connect any external monitors, or...
2. Change your JDK runtime to a version with the bug resolved:

   1. You will need to install a plugin to allow you to choose your runtime, see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under.
   2. Download and install a working runtime from https://adoptopenjdk.net/nightly.html?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=hotspot (i.e. version `11.0.9` works, no crashes but you lose some functionality such as accessing Preferences and Layout Editor)
   3. From Android Studio, choose the new runtime (**Help** > **Find Action...** > **Choose Runtime...**)

Unfortunately I have yet to find a runtime that doesn't compromise some kind of functionality in AS.

Comment: Are U kidding? :D I'll disconnect additional monitor and we will see

Comment: Small addition to this.  It's not when you open it on an external monitor, but when you open it on a non-primary external monitor.  If you have an external monitor and set it as primary (by going to display settings and dragging the mini-menubar to it), IntelliJ will not crash on the external monitor, but trying to drag the window to your "built-in" monitor will crash it

Comment: Using "jbsdk11b125_osx_x64.tar.gz" from Choose Runtime is working for me, even Preferences.  Layout Editor still doesn't work like you said.  I tried turning on the experimental layout rendering engine, but it crashed.

Comment: Good news: I've been using Big Sur 11.0.1 Release Candidate (20B5022a) for a few days now and I haven't been getting any crashes since.

Comment: I'm on Big Sur 11.0.1 (20B29) and it keeps crashing. Disconneting external monitor does not help.

Comment: It's been three years, and it is still happening to me! (Android Studio Giraffe)

Answer (score 23):

The IDE freezing when opening tabs is due to macOS's default settings. Go to **System Preferences > General > Prefer tabs** and select **never**.

Alternatively, you can run this command in Terminal if you want to keep tabs for all other apps except Android Studio (the ideal solution):

```
defaults write com.google.android.studio AppleWindowTabbingMode manual
```

Comment: Was looking for exactly this. You saved my day BIG TIME !!!

Comment: This was my issue. Ty!

Answer (score -1):

i did as what Andrew Wei said of the way2, i choose another runtime, it fixed this issue , but ererytime i open the layout design view or split view, it crashed again, i changed to other and other version runtime, one of this issue and crash on design view must be shown,  so i choose the lesser of tow evils, i will use avd to view the layout instead of design view or split view.

Comment: You should post this as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @Scarl , sorry, I was meant to comment but it tell me there was somewhing wrong with it , so I post as answer, sorry . I am new.