# Android Studio 4.1.1 macOS Full Screen Error

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

I've got a problem after updating Mac to Big Sur `11.0.1`.

All interstitial dialog windows, Device Manager, Preferences, SDK options, and etc, are not opened as interstitials/dialogs in fullscreen mode, but as a tab in-app. Then, Android Studio freezes and is not responding.

*i.e.: Commit Changes Window*

[image]

Any ideas how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Same here. I've tried removing all configuration/settings, SDKs, emulators and such. Rebooted. Fully fresh download and install. Starting with a new project. Might be related to the issue of some apps not starting up at all (https://appleinsider.com/articles/20/11/12/apple-system-issue-causing-app-install-runtime-problems)

Comment: Check this - [Android Studio freezes on macOS Big Sur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65392688/6244429)

Answer (score 277, accepted):

<kbd>System Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>General</kbd> > set <kbd>Prefer Tabs</kbd> to *never* when opening documents.

Alternatively, run this on Terminal and restart Android Studio:

```
defaults write com.google.android.studio AppleWindowTabbingMode manual
```

This works while keeping the tabs active for other apps.

Comment: Thanks! And for the macOS noobs like me, search for System Preferences in macOS, not in Android Studio ;)

Comment: For Chinese users, the option's title is "首选以标签页方式打开文稿".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, a restart is needed when using the terminal approach. The problem is still exists on macOS big Sur version 11.1, android studio version 4.1.2, the solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

Go to the Apple Menu, select System Preferences > General. In the Prefer tabs when opening documents option, select "never". Then restart Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks. Still feels like issues AS should fix but if this helps for now I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 6):

I solved by clicking the  -> System Preferences -> General -> Prefer Tabs and select "never". I have no problem using the latest version of IDEA, it may be that the version of IDEA on which Android Studio is based low.

Comment: On my Catalina version, the key combination's got messed up. I couldn't find Android Studio Preferences anywhere.

Comment: I had to work around by double press the `Shift` type in "plugin" in order to open the Preferences.

Comment: You can click Android Studio -> Preferences on macOS

Answer (score 0):

You can try : System Preferences > General > Prefer Tabs  and set #never when opening documents.
I hope solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the ideal place to fix this is in the native code in the app launcher. In AppBundler we recently made [this change](https://github.com/TheInfiniteKind/appbundler/commit/858c411dc706dbb99ec2b45c61f8adb2daecf370) which sets the tab mode before loading the JVM. It's basically the in-app equivalent of running "defaults write" in the terminal but doesn't require executing a process.