# Dialogs are displayed as tabs in Android Studio IDE then the IDE becomes unresponsive

Tags: macos, crash, ide, editor, android-studio-4.1

I am having a problem with **Android Studio 4.1** where particular things that should show up as dialogs(like *tip of the day* or an *update dialog*) are displayed as fullscreen tabs and then Android Studio becomes **unresponsive**, CPU usage goes through the roof and the fan kicks in almost immediately, and I have to **force it to quit**.

This is happening on **Mac** and I recently updated to **macOs Big Sur** but everything was working fine until 2 days ago when this started happening so I don't if I hit some key combination to make this happen or something else is wrong.

I deleted and reinstalled Android Studio but the problem still persists. Below is a screenshot of this happening when I had just got an alert about a Gradle Update and I clicked on update.

### EDIT

On trying to find out further what the problem could be, this only occurs when the Android Studio window is in maximised/fullscreen mode

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem in fullscreen, it seems it is related to big sur, I had to run this on the terminal and restart the android studio

```
defaults write com.google.android.studio AppleWindowTabbingMode manual
```

I found the tip here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64837992/2551801

This should help in the mean time a new stable version is released.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I tried to mark my question as a duplicate of yours but I need 2 more votes to mark as duplicate and close it, kindly flag this (my) question as a duplicate of yours and vote to close it. And thank you again

Comment: works well, thanks

Comment: I upgraded to Big Sur in the past couple weeks, and this was happening to me.  When the Big Sur 11.3.1 patch arrived shortly thereafter, the problem went away.