# Android Studio 4.1.1- MacOS BigSur - Freezing Problem in FullScreen

Tags: android, android-studio, macos-big-sur

I am using the latest version of Android Studio (4.1.1). After updating the Mac operating system, Android Studio started encountering strange errors.

The most annoying problem I have ever had. When I want to open a new github branch, the window appears as below and freezes.

[image]

This is what it should normally look like.

[image]

Of course, this is the only window problem I've noticed. The most important problem here is that the screen freezes and no action can be taken.

If people who have problems or have a solution on this issue share it with me, everyone will benefit. Thank you.

**Edit :** This issue has been officially resolved in Android Studio 4.2.

Comment: I don't know a solution, but a workaround: If you set "prefer tabs" to "never" in System Preferences → General while using Android Studio, the window is opened correctly and Android Studio doesn't freeze. Obviously not an optimal solution, since all apps will then use separate windows instead of tabs. I hope they fix this bug in the next Android Studio version.

Answer (score 125):

The problem is that when macOS is set to prefer tabs, Android Studio 4.1.1 on macOS Big Sur also opens things like branch settings in tabs instead of windows.

To fix it, you can prevent those tabs only in Android Studio.

Open Terminal and run this command:

`defaults write com.google.android.studio AppleWindowTabbingMode manual`

Now Android Studio will use windows again and not crash.

> **Solution was found on reddit** https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/jtbl4m/has_anyone_updated_to_macos_big_sur_and_is/gc8pfhg/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it didn't provide a radical solution. I think the Android Studio team will fix this problem.

Comment: @kzncrda Probably! For now I'm just glad to still be able to use it.

Comment: YES! This fixed it! Thank you.

Comment: I spend one whole day. its one command works perfectly.

Answer (score 55):

It's a known issue in Android Studio

As per [Developer page](https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues#ki-signed-apk-macos) -

Android Studio freezes on macOS Big Sur.
On machines running macOS Big Sur, Android Studio 4.1 might freeze when you open a dialog.

To work around this issue, do one of the following:

- Go to the Apple Menu, select **System Preferences > General**. In the **Prefer tabs when opening documents** option, select "never". Then restart Android Studio.
- Upgrade to Android Studio 4.2, currently available in the [Beta channel](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview).

Otherwise, wait for the Stable Android Studio 4.2

Comment: The first workaround is working for me, but the second one not (Android Studio 4.2 Beta 4).