# Android Studio Super-Slow, Lagging & Crashes on Any New Window Opening- Mac, Need Help Debugging

Tags: android-studio, macos-big-sur

After the latest Android Studio updates on MacBook Pro I have been having an issue making Android Studio completely unusable!

Every time I open a new window in Android Studio it semi-crashes until I force quit the program. If I attempt to open preferences, or create a new activity or even install the newest Kotlin beta the program crashes. Anything to do with opening a new window (seems to be the common denominator) crashes Studio.

Here is what happens: The window opens full-screen, unlike previously where all windows would open as a popup window. Android Studio starts lagging with all button presses 30 seconds to 2 minutes, it also starts using over 100% CPU power, gets super hot and destroys the battery as a result. For information, my laptop is powerful enough to run many open applications simultaneously without even a hiccup such as 3d modelling, Xcode, Android Studio, Chrome, etc. So computing power and memory is no issue.

I tried opening windows and creating new activities in my main project as well as a brand new project just in case it was a project issue but nope, same problems. I tried googling and no such issues. I wanted to check here to see if anyone has any advice or quick fixes before I attempt to uninstall and re-install.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio 4.1.1- MacOS BigSur - Freezing Problem in FullScreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64952961/android-studio-4-1-1-macos-bigsur-freezing-problem-in-fullscreen)

Comment: Yes Zoe, touché. Thank you, I added the best answer from this post below. It is the best option of solutions without needing to stop tabs from preferences because it was not there for my version for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer:

Run this in the terminal: `defaults write com.google.android.studio AppleWindowTabbingMode manual`

Source:
[Android Studio 4.1.1- MacOS BigSur - Freezing Problem in FullScreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64952961/android-studio-4-1-1-macos-bigsur-freezing-problem-in-fullscreen)

Answer (score 3):

in my case, this happens whenever android studio opens a new tab.

i fixed it by changing the system preferences to never open new documents in a new tab, thanks to a post on reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/jtbl4m/has_anyone_updated_to_macos_big_sur_and_is/.

System Preferences > General > Prefer Tabs "never" when opening documents.

Comment: According to that post it looks like it is a combination error between BigSur and Android Studio upgrade. Thats what i deduce since I rolled back Android Studio as per my answer above... That fixed it for me for the most part HOWEVER I am now having trouble again! Im trying to add an emulator to be able to screenshot tablet sizes for play store but every time the emulator window opens it freezes like before! Jeesh! What a dumb glitch! When I try the above solution there is no "prefer tabs never" option... Any inupt?

Comment: i was facing the same issue as well when opening the AVD manager "in tab mode" and it seems like this also happens when android studio is on full screen mode, it was solved when i changed my "prefered tabs mode" to never. you should be able to solve it the same way, just note that you need to change it from the "System preferences" of the mac itself not from android studio's preferences.
so from the top left corner of the screen click on the "apple icon/logo" then System Preferences > General > Prefer Tabs "never"

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it finally, could not wait for an answer.

I ended up uninstalling with this info here: https://howchoo.com/macos/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-on-macos-and-os-x

run the following in terminal:

```
    rm -Rf /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
    rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*
    rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.android.*
    rm -Rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.android.*
    rm -Rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio*
    rm -Rf ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*
    rm -Rf ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio*
    rm -Rf ~/.AndroidStudio*
```

I then installed the previous working Studio (4.1) here: https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html

Hope this might help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Select

```
Apple Menu --> System Preferences --> General --> Prefer tabs
```

Select `never`. Then restart Android Studio.

I am using Android Studio 4.1, but you can upgrade to available version