# Android Studio Getting Stuck

Tags: android-studio

After updating the Android Studio it has started getting stuck and shows tabs for settings/preferences or any other option that previously used to open in a dialog.
If I try to open a new project then also it shows in a single window with a separate tab.
Please let me know how can I fix this, thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64837992/1595156) after wasting a whole day.