# Latest Android Studio opening every window or popup in full screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I upgraded to latest Android Studio version (4.1.1) and it started opening every popup or dialogue in full screen and it freezes my system also for a few seconds or even minutes sometimes. Any help?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on Mac, this is likely a problem with the latest Big Sur update. Check out the following answer for the solution.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64837992/520961