# Android Studio dialog box is not opening properly and not able to close

Tags: android-studio, macos-big-sur

After upgrading Android Studio, the dialog box is not coming properly. It's opening in full screen and it's not closing, I tried to click close buttons but it is not working. Every time I need to force quit the android studio and reopen it. Screenshot attached below.

Please let me know any solution to fix this. I am using

> Macbook Pro - macOS Big Sur v-11.1
>
> Android Studio - 4.1.2

[image: Android Studio dialog issue]

Comment: found the answer here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64827350/android-studio-4-1-1-macos-full-screen-error/64837992](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64827350/android-studio-4-1-1-macos-full-screen-error/64837992)