# android studio freezing on m1 mac

Tags: flutter, macos, android-studio, freeze, apple-m1

I am using `Android Studio` for `Flutter`. The problem is that my `android studio freezes` regularly many times. It is very annoying. It is ver weird as my `RAM is 16GB` which is very enough for the mac with high specs. I `don't use simulator/emulator`.

This usually happens `when I start typing in pubspec.yaml`. it freezes for about `10+ seconds` as soon as I start typing.

I would really appreciate if you could help how to resolve this issue!

Here is the flutter doctor output if it can help:

[image]

Comment: this might be helpful [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64827350/android-studio-4-1-1-macos-full-screen-error/64837992#64837992)

Comment: this didn't work for me

Answer (score 3):

I think I found a solution. I doubted why it was happening on my `pubspec.yaml` almost all the time. Then, I remembered I was using `Flutter Pub Version Checker` plugin. It was the reason why AS was freezing.

Just I needed to disable this plugin.

Comment: thanks a lot man.  u made my job easy

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same issue I am not able to open android studio file sometimes so I ask my seniors and they told me to do following steps and it will work for me

**Open sdk manager then go to system settings**

**inside system settings go to memory settings and increase IDE max heap
size**

this problem occurs when you use library in your project so your project has to use more ram

Comment: This didn't help either. I doubled the heapsize. I am not even using 1/4 of the ram given to my AS

Comment: even i try to delete one symbol from the pubspec.yaml it freezes. Crazy!

Comment: can you share your flutter doctor?

Comment: I have added it to the question

Comment: seems like everything is perfect when I got proper reason I will answer this question

Comment: I think I found the solution