# Android Studio gets freezing in MacOs Big Sur Update

Tags: macos, android-studio, macos-big-sur

I have updated my MacOs to Big Sur update, And I am unable to work smoothly when I am opening the two projects and the Android studio gets freeze. Also when I am adding a file git it again freezes opening into a new tab. Also, It freezes when I am trying to use setter and getter methods. Is this issue with the new update from MacOs or it is from the Android studio update? Is there any fix for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Solve for me, https://stackoverflow.com/a/64907362/2767337

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, after hours of searching for this issue, I got a solution.

We can disable a freezing pop-up of the android studio in MacOs bigSur version by using a command in the terminal.

Running this on Terminal works while keeping the tabs active for other apps

**

> defaults write com.google.android.studio AppleWindowTabbingMode manual

**